# Servant: How to serve a nested api?

Tags: haskell, servant

I'm following the documentation and exactly in this part https://docs.servant.dev/en/v0.6/tutorial/Server.html#nested-apis I got stuck.

They were showing how to make a nested api, but in the part of implementation they left it as a homework. I tried repeat what I've doing so far, but I ain't got no luck.

I keep getting this error message:

> • No instance for (aeson-1.4.7.1:Data.Aeson.Types.ToJSON.ToJSON
> User)
> arising from a use of ‘serve’ • In the expression: serve combinedAPI server3   In an equation for ‘app3’: app3 = serve
> combinedAPI server3

In this documentation I've already spotted some versioning issues, i'm using Server 0.18.3 and maybe there's some new syntax that is not allowing the code to work. That's why I haven't try to enforce this exactly aeson version yet, I really think this it is a type or syntax problem.

Here is the code from my Nested.hs, the same as in the documentation, I want to use my app3 in my Main.hs and that's how I'm doing it.

Meaningful part of Nested.hs

```
type CombinedAPI =
  "users" :> UsersAPI
    :<|> "products" :> ProductsAPI

server3 :: Server CombinedAPI
server3 = usersServer :<|> productsServer
  

combinedAPI :: Proxy CombinedAPI
combinedAPI = Proxy

app3 :: Application
app3 = serve combinedAPI server3
```

Main.hs

```
module Main where

import Network.Wai.Handler.Warp
import qualified Server
import qualified Api
import qualified LucidExample
import qualified Nested

main :: IO ()
main =
    -- run 8081 Server.app1
    -- run 8081 Api.app
    -- run 8081 LucidExample.app2
    run 8081 Nested.app3
```

Nested.hs

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}

module Nested where

import Data.Time.Calendar (Day)
import GHC.Generics (Generic)
import Servant

-- GET /:userid
-- DELETE /:userid

data User = User
  { name :: String,
    age :: Int,
    email :: String,
    registration_date :: Day
  }
  deriving (Eq, Show, Generic)

-- Each handler receives the userid argument
type UserAPI =
  Capture "userid" Int :> Get '[JSON] User
    :<|> Capture "userid" Int :> DeleteNoContent

-- Same as UserAPI but condensed, the whole server takes the userid
type UserAPI2 =
  Capture "userid" Int
    :> ( Get '[JSON] User
           :<|> DeleteNoContent
       )

-- Server UserAPI3 = (Int -> Handler User)
--                     :<|> (Int -> Handler NoContent)

-- Server UserAPI4 = (Int -> Handler User)
--                     :<|> (Int -> Handler NoContent)

server :: Server UserAPI
server = getUser :<|> deleteUser
  where
    getUser :: Int -> Handler User
    getUser _userid = undefined

    deleteUser :: Int -> Handler NoContent
    deleteUser _userid = undefined

server2 :: Server UserAPI2
server2 userid = getUser userid :<|> deleteUser userid
  where
    getUser :: Int -> Handler User
    getUser = undefined

    deleteUser :: Int -> Handler NoContent
    deleteUser = undefined

-- GET /users
-- GET /users/:userid
type API1 =
  "users"
    :> ( Get '[JSON] [User] --user listing
           :<|> Capture "userid" Int :> Get '[JSON] User -- view a particular User
       )

type API2 =
  ReqBody '[JSON] User
    :> ( Get '[JSON] User --just display the same user back, don't register it
           :<|> PostNoContent -- register the user, empty response
       )

type UsersAPI =
  Get '[JSON] [User] -- list users
    :<|> ReqBody '[JSON] User
      :> PostNoContent -- add a user
    :<|> Capture "userid" Int
      :> ( Get '[JSON] User -- view a user
             :<|> ReqBody '[JSON] User
             :> PutNoContent -- update a user
             :<|> DeleteNoContent -- delete a user
         )

usersServer :: Server UsersAPI
usersServer = getUsers :<|> newUser :<|> userOperations
  where
    getUsers :: Handler [User]
    getUsers = error "..."

    newUser :: User -> Handler NoContent
    newUser = error "..."

    userOperations userid =
      viewUser userid :<|> updateUser userid :<|> deleteUser userid
      where
        viewUser :: Int -> Handler User
        viewUser = error "..."

        updateUser :: Int -> User -> Handler NoContent
        updateUser = error "..."

        deleteUser :: Int -> Handler NoContent
        deleteUser = error "..."

type ProductsAPI =
  Get '[JSON] [Product] -- list products
    :<|> ReqBody '[JSON] Product :> PostNoContent -- add a product
    :<|> Capture "productid" Int
      :> ( Get '[JSON] Product -- view a product
             :<|> ReqBody '[JSON] Product :> PutNoContent -- update a product
             :<|> DeleteNoContent -- delete a product
         )

newtype Product = Product {productId :: Int}

productsServer :: Server ProductsAPI
productsServer = getProducts :<|> newProduct :<|> productOperations
  where
    getProducts :: Handler [Product]
    getProducts = error "..."

    newProduct :: Product -> Handler NoContent
    newProduct = error "..."

    productOperations productid =
      viewProduct productid :<|> updateProduct productid :<|> deleteProduct productid
      where
        viewProduct :: Int -> Handler Product
        viewProduct = error "..."

        updateProduct :: Int -> Product -> Handler NoContent
        updateProduct = error "..."

        deleteProduct :: Int -> Handler NoContent
        deleteProduct = error "..."

type CombinedAPI =
  "users" :> UsersAPI
    :<|> "products" :> ProductsAPI

server3 :: Server CombinedAPI
server3 = usersServer :<|> productsServer
  

combinedAPI :: Proxy CombinedAPI
combinedAPI = Proxy

app3 :: Application
app3 = serve combinedAPI server3
```

Comment: I don't think the nesting is the problem here. The error message says you don't have a `ToJSON` instance for `User`, and having searched your code, you indeed don't - yet you need that if you want that endpoint to handle JSON. You already derive `Generic` so all you should need to do is put an empty instance (unless you want to customise the JSON representation of your user values): `instance ToJSON User`. (You'll also need to import that class from the `Aeson` package of course.)

Comment: (I just checked the tutorial you linked to, that indeed is in their example code, you just seem to have overlooked it - which is easy enough to do. Surprised the error message didn't help you realise this mistake though.)

Comment: Come on man, give me a break, haskell is almost greek to me. Since I read your response, I made a lot of progress though. I got stuck on others things but I didn't give up yet. You can finish this implementation to make your answer, doing so I will choose you as best answer, otherwise I shall make my own answer to this question.

Comment: Apologies. There was nothing in your message which indicated that you were new to Haskell. And Servant uses a lot of advanced features of the language (indeed ones which aren't technically part of the standard language, but are enabled by extensions in the GHC compiler), so I would never recommend a Haskell beginner to try using it.